# Pandas df get previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with null values:

| index | fecha | code | Place | dato1 | porcentaje_dato1 | dato2 | dato3 | porcentaje_dato3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-04 | 1 | Place1 | 25809 | 0.3 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 2 | Place2 | 2004 | 0.15 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | 3 | Place3 | 9380 | 0.92 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2021-01-04 | 4 | Place4 | 153 | 0.01 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 20 | 2021-01-05 | 1 | Place1 | 40263 | 0.47 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 21 | 2021-01-05 | 2 | Place2 | 2985 | 0.22 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 22 | 2021-01-05 | 3 | Place3 | 12929 | 1.27 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 23 | 2021-01-05 | 4 | Place4 | 2656 | 0.22 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 40 | 2021-01-07 | 1 | Place1 | 53934 | 0.64 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 41 | 2021-01-07 | 2 | Place2 | 6186 | 0.46 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 42 | 2021-01-07 | 3 | Place3 | 14406 | 1.42 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 43 | 2021-01-07 | 4 | Place4 | 3190 | 0.26 | NaN | NaN | 0.0 |
| 1415 | 2021-04-14 | 1 | Place1 | 1970183 | 23.23 | 1419209.0 | 550974.0 | 6.5 |
| 1416 | 2021-04-14 | 2 | Place2 | 331419 | 24.89 | 228547.0 | 102872.0 | 7.73 |
| 1417 | 2021-04-14 | 3 | Place3 | 317019 | 31.22 | 216006.0 | 101013.0 | 9.95 |
| 1418 | 2021-04-14 | 4 | Place4 | 233042 | 19.18 | 175460.0 | 57582.0 | 4.74 |
| 1436 | 2021-04-15 | 1 | Place1 | 2041844 | 24.07 | 1481837.0 | 560007.0 | 6.6 |
| 1437 | 2021-04-15 | 2 | Place2 | 347963 | 26.14 | 243497.0 | 104466.0 | 7.85 |
| 1438 | 2021-04-15 | 3 | Place3 | 330038 | 32.5 | 225213.0 | 104825.0 | 10.32 |
| 1439 | 2021-04-15 | 4 | Place4 | 240488 | 19.79 | 180775.0 | 59713.0 | 4.91 |

If value of dato2 is null, I need to fill it with dato1 value and sum previous day value for same place. Steps to implement are

- first order by place and date
- iterate dataframe. For each row

  - Check if it is first row of entire df. If so, dato2 = dato1
  - check if place has change (if place of actual row is different than place of previous row). Then dato2 = dato1
  - else: dato2 = dato2 previous row + dato1 actual row

code I have is

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['place', 'fecha']) 
for i, row in df.iterrows():
  if pd.isnull(row['dato2']):
    if i == 0:
      df['dato2'][i] = df['dato1'][i]
    elif df['place'][i] != df['place'][i-1]:
      df['dato2'][i] = df['dato1'][i]
    else:
      df['dato2'][i] = df['dato2'][i-1] + df_vac['dato1'][i]
  else:
    df['dato2'][i]
```

But with this code indexes are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach.

```py
# Sort dataframe
df = (pd.read_csv(data)
        .sort_values(['Place','fecha']
        .reset_index())

# Fill missing values for dato2 with dato1
df['dato2'] = df.dato2.fillna(df.dato1)

# Calculate the aggregate, store in separate df
df_agg = (df[['Place','fecha','dato2']].groupby(['Place','fecha']).sum()
                                       .groupby('Place').cumsum()
                                       .reset_index())

# Update original data
df.update(df_agg)
```

Result:

| index | fecha | code | Place | dato1 | porcentaje_dato1 | dato2 | dato3 | porcentaje_dato3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-01-04 | 1 | Place1 | 25809 | 0.30 | 25809.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 4 | 2021-01-05 | 1 | Place1 | 40263 | 0.47 | 66072.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 8 | 2021-01-07 | 1 | Place1 | 53934 | 0.64 | 120006.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 12 | 2021-04-14 | 1 | Place1 | 1970183 | 23.23 | 1539215.0 | 550974.0 | 6.50 |
| 16 | 2021-04-15 | 1 | Place1 | 2041844 | 24.07 | 3021052.0 | 560007.0 | 6.60 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | 2 | Place2 | 2004 | 0.15 | 2004.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 5 | 2021-01-05 | 2 | Place2 | 2985 | 0.22 | 4989.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 9 | 2021-01-07 | 2 | Place2 | 6186 | 0.46 | 11175.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 13 | 2021-04-14 | 2 | Place2 | 331419 | 24.89 | 239722.0 | 102872.0 | 7.73 |
| 17 | 2021-04-15 | 2 | Place2 | 347963 | 26.14 | 483219.0 | 104466.0 | 7.85 |
| 2 | 2021-01-04 | 3 | Place3 | 9380 | 0.92 | 9380.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 6 | 2021-01-05 | 3 | Place3 | 12929 | 1.27 | 22309.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 10 | 2021-01-07 | 3 | Place3 | 14406 | 1.42 | 36715.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 14 | 2021-04-14 | 3 | Place3 | 317019 | 31.22 | 252721.0 | 101013.0 | 9.95 |
| 18 | 2021-04-15 | 3 | Place3 | 330038 | 32.50 | 477934.0 | 104825.0 | 10.32 |
| 3 | 2021-01-04 | 4 | Place4 | 153 | 0.01 | 153.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 7 | 2021-01-05 | 4 | Place4 | 2656 | 0.22 | 2809.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 11 | 2021-01-07 | 4 | Place4 | 3190 | 0.26 | 5999.0 | NaN | 0.00 |
| 15 | 2021-04-14 | 4 | Place4 | 233042 | 19.18 | 181459.0 | 57582.0 | 4.74 |
| 19 | 2021-04-15 | 4 | Place4 | 240488 | 19.79 | 362234.0 | 59713.0 | 4.91 |